# How to open new browser window in intern js?

Tags: javascript, selenium, intern, leadfoot

I am automating the UI test of my application. There are some cases when i want my test script to close the current  browser and and run next test by opening new browser. The problem is that I am unable to figure out how to open new browser window in intern. `remote.get(URL)` doesn't do what i want to do here. Can someone please help.

I have updated my question to include code as well. My question is pretty much straight forward though. **How to open new browser window using intern from inside test ?**.
though if you want to see the code please comment, I will write it down .
Thanks.

```
        // in tests/functional/index.js
 define([
 'intern!object',
'intern/chai!assert',
'Automation/ConfigFiles/dataurl',
'Automation/pages/login/loginpage',
'intern/dojo/node!fs',
'intern/dojo/node!leadfoot/helpers/pollUntil'
  ], function (registerSuite, assert, dataurl, LoginPage, fs, pollUntil) {
registerSuite(function () {
    var loginPage;
    var values;
    return {
        setup: function () {
            var data = fs.readFileSync(loginpage, 'utf8');
            json = JSON.parse(data);
            values = json.values;
            loginPage = new LoginPage(this.remote, json.locator);
            return this.remote
           .get(require.toUrl(json.locator.URL)).setFindTimeout(60000000000).sleep(5000)
        },

        beforeEach:function() {
           // here i want to open new window

        },

        'valid loginname lands to password page':function () {
            loginPage.submitLoginName(values.unamevalue);
            loginPage.isPasswordPageDisplayed().then(function(isPasswordPageDisplayed) {
                assert.true(isPasswordPageDisplayed, 'password page is not displayed, Invalid Login name');
            })
        },

        'successful login': function () {   
            loginPage
                .login(values.unamevalue, values.pwdvalue)
            loginPage.isLoginSuccess().then(function (loginSuccess) {
                assert.isTrue(loginSuccess, 'Login Failed');
            });
        },
        afterEach: function () {
            return this.remote.closeCurrentWindow()
        }
    };
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `window.open()`?

Comment: yeah , I tried that but i m not sure how to include `window` in script , because it is giving `window is not defined` error .

Comment: Hmm... can't help here much more than that, no Intern experience :P

Comment: So you need to add some code to your queston. window should work, yet it is not defined in your script. Need more information.

Comment: updated my question to add code.

Comment: Where is/was the window.open call?

Comment: no there is not . I tried to but use it but got above mentioned error.

Answer (score 2):

You can open a new window with `window.open`. The trick is that you want to run that command in the remote browser. Intern (technically Leadfoot) gives you two methods for doing that on `this.remote`: `execute` and `executeAsync`. For example, to simply open a new window, you could do:

```
this.remote.execute(function () {
    window.open();
})
```

Once you've opened a new window, you need to switch to it to interact with it. A script might look something like:

```
var windowHandles;
this.remote
    .getAllWindowHandles()
    .then(function (handles) {
        windowHandles = handles;
    })
    .execute(function () { window.open() })
    .sleep(500)
    .getAllWindowHandles()
    .then(function (handles) {
        // compare the new handles to windowHandles to figure out which
        // is the new window, then switch to it
        return this.remote.switchToWindow(newWindowHandle);
    })

    .get('some_new_url')
    // rest of test
```

Comment: Thanks @jason0x43 for the response. Your answer basically opens a new tab. What i want to do is different than your answer .                                    I want to :                                                                                                     1. close the browser when first test is executed (now there is no browser ).                                                                                                    2. Open new browser and execute next test.

Comment: If you want to close the existing browser window, add a `closeCurrentWindow` before the second `getAllWindowHandles`. I'd assumed you might want to keep it open for debugging purposes. As for opening a new tab vs a new window, try providing window arguments, like `window.open('url', 'name', 'height=500,width=600')`.